# Solution to ODE $\frac{d^2z(x)}{dx^2}=b\cdot e^{(-a\cdot z(x))}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, transformation

I am looking for solution $z(x)$ ($z$ as function of $x$) to differential equation. This is the eikonal in geometric optics that describes the rays direction for hot air over a surface (mirage).

$$\frac{d^2z(x)}{dx^2}=b\cdot e^{(-a\cdot z(x))}$$

Variable $x$, and $a$ and $b$ are constants. How to solve it ?

I am trying to solve it using Laplace transformation. And would like to ask what is the Laplace transform of $\exp(-a\cdot z(x))$

$Ys^2-s\cdot y(0)-y\prime(0)=?$

Comment: Is $z(x)$ another function? or is it $e^{-azx}$

Comment: It's a **nonlinear** ODE, so don't expect too much from the Laplace transform...

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_x[\exp (-z(x))](s)$ is not in any tables.It maybe may exist, but we do not know yet.

Comment: If you set $z'(x)=f(z(x))$ trying to find a suitable $f$, or just multiply with $z'$ and integrate, you get a first order ODE.

Comment: No need for Laplace transform. That is an ODE of automonoous kind. HINT : multiply by $\frac{dz}{dx}$ and integrate. This reduces to a separable first order ODE. Explicit solution can be derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d^2z}{dx^2}=be^{-az}$

$\dfrac{dz}{dx}\dfrac{d^2z}{dx^2}=be^{-az}\dfrac{dz}{dx}$

$\int\dfrac{dz}{dx}\dfrac{d^2z}{dx^2}~dx=\int be^{-az}\dfrac{dz}{dx}~dx$

$\int\dfrac{dz}{dx}~d\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)=\int be^{-az}~dz$

$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)^2=-\dfrac{be^{-az}}{a}+c$

$\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)^2=\dfrac{C_1-be^{-az}}{a}$

$\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{C_1-be^{-az}}}{\sqrt a}$

Comment: Thanks. The solution on this link seems to be a bit different  page 7 http://student.ndhu.edu.tw/~d9914102/Teaching/102-2%20OP/data/102-2/Appendix-I_C3_The_Eikonal_Equation.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-azx}e^{-sx}dx=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x(az+s)}dx=-\frac{e^{-x(az+s)}}{az+s}|_{0}^\infty=\frac{1}{az+s}$$

Comment: Thanks. But it is z as function of x, z(x)

Comment: I see, unfortunately I don't believe there is a set formula for a general Laplace transform for $e^{z(x)}$ so unless more info was given I'm afraid I can't help you. See this table of Laplace Transforms: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf